# R - SixSigma - ss.study.ca

Tags: r, rgui, tinn-r

when I run ss.study.ca example at website "https://rdrr.io/cran/SixSigma/man/ss.study.ca.html" , the graphic shows the Ppk value (Bottom-Right).

When I run it locally using Tinn-R or RGui, this Ppk value does not appear.

I have install the software on 02/08/2018 and update all packages: Sixsigma, colorspace, Rcpp and stringi.

Any ideas?